# Strange "Memory Leak Detection" error C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory, memory-leaks

I have a very strange problem with memory leaks. I use _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks for checking leaks. Here is my WinMain function:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    ////////////////// SET UP CHECKS FOR MEMORY LEAKS ////////////////////
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // Reports leaks to stderr

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have removed completely everything from it just to check if maybe I get some kind of false alarms.

After I close an application, I get this bunch of memory leaks in the output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{1343} normal block at 0x06076780, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < g      > 20 67 07 06 00 00 00 00 
{1342} normal block at 0x06076710, 52 bytes long.
 Data: <@   @   @       > 40 16 07 06 40 16 07 06 40 16 07 06 01 00 CD CD 
{1341} normal block at 0x060766B0, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <C:/Windows/Fonts> 43 3A 2F 57 69 6E 64 6F 77 73 2F 46 6F 6E 74 73 
{1339} normal block at 0x0607F438, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <              P > C0 17 0B 01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 80 13 50 04 
{1338} normal block at 0x04501380, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <    H   > BC 0D 0B 01 48 18 07 06 
{1295} normal block at 0x060716B0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > B4 B3 0B 01 00 00 00 00 
{1294} normal block at 0x06071640, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < g   g   g      > 10 67 07 06 10 67 07 06 10 67 07 06 01 01 CD CD 
{1293} normal block at 0x0450DFB8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < !    P > E0 21 0B 01 98 05 50 04 
{1292} normal block at 0x0450E110, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  P     > E8 05 50 04 00 00 00 00 
// (There's like thousand more of those...)
Object dump complete.
```

I have completely no idea where do them come from.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Output window.  Do you see a bunch of DLLs being loaded?  Any of them may be statically initializing data structures  that are not freed before you call the leak output.  Try the tip [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-suppress-the-memory-leak-messages-on-windows) to exclude some of that noise, by bracketing your leak check to a certain range of execution time.

> Since the statically initialized Google Test singleton requires allocations on the heap, the Visual C++ memory leak detector will report memory leaks at the end of the program run. The easiest way to avoid this is to use the _CrtMemCheckpoint and _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince calls to not report any statically initialized heap objects. See MSDN for more details and additional heap check/debug routines.